# Error 404 on a view that exists on routes. The URL exists as well as the view but it keeps returning error 404

Tags: php, laravel

I am getting an error 404 from a view that actually exists in my routes.
This is the view where I select the data from (sidebar.blade.php)

```
<div class="col-xl-3 col-lg-3 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 sidebar-shop-left">
                    <div class="product-categori">
                        <div class="search-product">
                            <form action="#">
                                <input class="form-control" placeholder="Search here..." type="text">
                                <button type="submit"> <i class="fa fa-search"></i> </button>
                            </form>
                        </div>
                        <div class="filter-sidebar-left">
                            <div class="title-left">
                                <h3>Categories</h3>
                            </div>
                            <div class="list-group list-group-collapse list-group-sm list-group-tree" id="list-group-men" data-children=".sub-men">
                                @foreach($categories as $cat)
                                <div class="list-group-collapse sub-men">
                                    <a class="list-group-item list-group-item-action" href="#{{$cat->id}}" data-toggle="collapse" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="sub-men1">{{$cat->name}}
                                </a>
                                    <div class="collapse hide" id="{{$cat->id}}" data-parent="#list-group-men">
                                    @foreach($cat->categories as $subcat)
                                    @if($subcat->status==1)
                                        <div class="list-group">
                                            <a href="{{ asset('resume/'.$subcat->url) }}" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action active">{{$subcat->name}}</a>
                                        </div>
                                        @endif
                                @endforeach
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                @endforeach
                            </div>
                        </div>


                    </div>
                </div>
```

This my routes file i.e (web.php).

```
// use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Web Routes
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Here is where you can register web routes for your application. These
| routes are loaded by the RouteServiceProvider within a group which
| contains the "web" middleware group. Now create something great!
|
*/


    // All Routes after Login
    Route::group(['middleware'=>['frontlogin']],function(){

        Route::get('/view-job','frontController@view');

        Route::match(['get', 'post'], '/browse', 'frontController@browse');

        Route::get('/resume/{url}','ResumeController@resumes');

        // Resume Detail Page
        Route::get('/resume/{id}','ResumeController@resume');

    });

    Route::match(['get', 'post'], '/how', 'frontController@how');

    Route::get('/logout', 'AdminController@logout');
```

This is the controller of the view file frontController.blade.php (browse_categories.blade.php). The function is browse()

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Input;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Mail;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Redirect;
use App\Category;
use App\Country;
use App\Enquiry;
use App\Resume;
use App\User;
use App\Job;
use Validator;
use Auth;
use Session;
use Image;
use DB;

class frontController extends Controller
{

    public function browse(){
        $title='Browse Categories';

        $resume = Resume::get();
        foreach($resume as $key => $val){
            $category_name = Category::where(['id' => $val->category_id])->first();
            $resume[$key]->category_name = $category_name->name;
        }
        $resume = json_decode(json_encode($resume));
        // echo "<pre>"; print_r($resume); die;


        $categories_menu = "";
        $categories = Category::with('categories')->where(['parent_id' => 0])->get();
        $categories = json_decode(json_encode($categories));

        return view('pages.browse_categories')->with(compact('categories_menu', 'categories', 'resume'), 'title', $title);
    }


}
```

This is the view file I get the error 404 (detail.blade.php)

```
@section('content')

<!-- Start All Title Box -->
<div class="all-title-box">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-12">
                    <h2>Details</h2>
                    <!-- <ul class="breadcrumb">
                        <li class="breadcrumb-item"><a href="/">Home</a></li>
                        <li class="breadcrumb-item active">Browse</li>
                    </ul> -->
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- End All Title Box -->

    <!-- Start Shop Page  -->
    <div class="shop-box-inner">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                @include('layouts.frontLayouts.frontSidebar')
                <div class="col-xl-9 col-lg-9 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 shop-content-right">
                    <div class="right-product-box">
                        <div class="product-item-filter row">
                            <div class="col-12 col-sm-8 text-center text-sm-left">
                                <!-- <div class="toolbar-sorter-right">
                                    <span>Sort by </span>
                                    <select id="basic" class="selectpicker show-tick form-control" data-placeholder="$ USD">
                                    <option data-display="Select">Nothing</option>
                                    <option value="1">Popularity</option>
                                    <option value="2">High Price → High Price</option>
                                    <option value="3">Low Price → High Price</option>
                                    <option value="4">Best Selling</option>
                                </select>
                                </div> -->
                                <p>Profile Details</p>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-12 col-sm-4 text-center text-sm-right">
                                <!-- <ul class="nav nav-tabs ml-auto">
                                    <li>
                                        <a class="nav-link" href="#grid-view" data-toggle="tab"> <i class="fa fa-th"></i> </a>
                                    </li>
                                    <li>
                                        <a class="nav-link active" href="#list-view" data-toggle="tab"> <i class="fa fa-list-ul"></i> </a>
                                    </li> -->
                                </ul>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="row product-categorie-box">
                            <div class="tab-content">
                                <!-- <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane fade" id="grid-view">
                                    <div class="row">

                                        <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-4 col-xl-4">
                                        @foreach($resume as $res)
                                            <div class="products-single fix">
                                                <div class="box-img-hover">
                                                @if(!empty($res->image))
                                                    <img src="{{ asset('/images/uploads/passport/small/'.$res->image) }}" class="img-fluid" alt="Image">
                                                    @endif
                                                    <div class="mask-icon">
                                                        <a class="cart" href="{{ url('/resume/'.$res->id) }}">View Profile</a>
                                                    </div>
                                                </div>
                                                <div class="why-text">
                                                    <h4>{{ $res->user_name}}</h4>
                                                    <h5> {{ $res->category_name}}</h5>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                        @endforeach
                                    </div>
                                </div> -->

                                <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane fade show active" id="list-view">
                                    <div class="list-view-box">
                                        <div class="row">
                                            <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-4 col-xl-4">
                                                <div class="products-single fix">
                                                    <div class="box-img-hover">
                                                        <!-- <div class="type-lb">
                                                            <p class="sale">Sale</p>
                                                        </div> -->
                                                        <img src="{{ asset('/images/uploads/passport/medium/'.$resumeDetails->image) }}" class="img-fluid" alt="Image">
                                                        <!-- <div class="mask-icon">
                                                            <ul>
                                                                <li><a href="#" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="right" title="View"><i class="fas fa-eye"></i></a></li>
                                                                <li><a href="#" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="right" title="Compare"><i class="fas fa-sync-alt"></i></a></li>
                                                                <li><a href="#" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="right" title="Add to Wishlist"><i class="far fa-heart"></i></a></li>
                                                            </ul>

                                                        </div> -->
                                                    </div>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-8 col-xl-8">
                                                <div class="why-text full-width">
                                                    <h4>{{ $resumeDetails ->user_name }}</h4>
                                                    <h5>Expected Salary ${{ $resumeDetails->salary}}</h5>
                                                    <p>Staff Information: {{ $resumeDetails->summary}}</p>
                                                    <a class="btn hvr-hover" href="#">Message</a>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- End Shop Page -->

    @endsection
```

This is the controller of the view file where I get the error 404 i.e detail.blade.php (Resume Controller) The function is resume

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Input;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Mail;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Redirect;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Validator;
use App\Resume;
use App\Category;
use App\Country;
use App\User;
use Auth;
use Session;
use Image;
use DB;

class ResumeController extends Controller
{


    public function resumes($url=null){

        $categoryCount = Category::where(['url'=>$url,'status'=>1])->count();
        if($categoryCount==0){
            abort(404);
        }

        $categories = Category::with('categories')->where(['parent_id' => 0])->get();

        $categoryDetails = Category::where(['url'=>$url])->first();
        if($categoryDetails->parent_id==0){
            $subCategories = Category::where(['parent_id'=>$categoryDetails->id])->get();
            $subCategories = json_decode(json_encode($subCategories));
            foreach($subCategories as $subcat){
                $cat_ids[] = $subcat->id;
            }

            $resumeAll = Resume::whereIn('resume.category_id', $cat_ids)->where('resume.status','1')->orderBy('resume.id','Desc');
            $breadcrumb = "<a href='/'>Home</a> / <a href='".$categoryDetails->url."'>".$categoryDetails->name."</a>";
        }else{
            $resumeAll = Resume::where(['resume.category_id'=>$categoryDetails->id])->where('resume.status','1')->orderBy('resume.id','Desc');
            $mainCategory = Category::where('id',$categoryDetails->parent_id)->first();
            $breadcrumb = "<a href='/'>Home</a> / <a href='".$mainCategory->url."'>".$mainCategory->name."</a> / <a href='".$categoryDetails->url."'>".$categoryDetails->name."</a>";   
        }

        $resumeAll = $resumeAll->paginate(6);
        // $resumeAll = json_decode(json_encode($resumeAll));
        // echo "<pre>"; print_r($resumeAll); die;

        return view('pages.listing')->with(compact('categories','resumeAll','categoryDetails','url','breadcrumb'));


    }

    public function resume($id = null){

         // Show 404 Page if resume is disabled
         $resumeCount = Resume::where(['id'=>$id,'status'=>1])->count();
         if($resumeCount==0){
             abort(404);
         }

         // Get resume Details
         $resumeDetails = Resume::with('experience')->where('id',$id)->first();
         $relatedResumes = Resume::where('id','!=',$id)->where(['category_id' => $resumeDetails->category_id])->get();

         $categories = Category::with('categories')->where(['parent_id' => 0])->get();

         $categoryDetails = Category::where('id',$resumeDetails->category_id)->first();
         if($categoryDetails->parent_id==0){
             $breadcrumb = "<a href='/'>Home</a> / <a href='".$categoryDetails->url."'>".$categoryDetails->name."</a> / ".$resumeDetails->user_name;
         }else{
             $mainCategory = Category::where('id',$categoryDetails->parent_id)->first();
             $breadcrumb = "<a style='color:#333;' href='/'>Home</a> / <a style='color:#333;' href='/resume/".$mainCategory->url."'>".$mainCategory->name."</a> / <a style='color:#333;' href='/resume/".$categoryDetails->url."'>".$categoryDetails->name."</a> / ".$resumeDetails->user_name;   
         }

         $meta_title = $resumeDetails->user_name;
        $meta_description = $resumeDetails->summary;
        $meta_keywords = $resumeDetails->user_name;
        return view('pages.detail')->with(compact('resumeDetails','categories','relatedResumes','meta_title','meta_description','meta_keywords','breadcrumb'));
    }

    public function deleteResume($id = null){
        Resume::where(['id'=>$id])->delete();
        return redirect()->back()->with('flash_message_success', 'Resume has been deleted successfully');
    }

}
```

Comment: Lots of code. Can you trim this down to the route you visit and its actual controller?

Comment: I have already edited the code to the two controllers and the routes

Comment: So it is two routes that throw a 404? What are the routes/urls? Have you tried commenting your `abort(404)` to make sure it isn't them causing the error?

Comment: Might be your `Route::get('/resume/{url}'` and `Route::get('/resume/{id}'` routes, both the same with different parameters

Comment: I have tried commenting it out, still the same issue

Comment: Your question has a lot of unnecessary information like the html markup. You also need to word it better so it's easier for people who wants to help you to understand. Controllers handle routes and you can do whatever you want inside them. Even tho you can return views from the controllers, that's not the "rule", so you better not refer as the "controller for your view" because that's confusing, instead say "controllers for my routes/endpoints".

Comment: You also need to point out exactly what are the routes that are giving you the `404`, the controller responsible of that route and the method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Overall Solution: Replace `url('/resume/'.$res->id)` with `action('ResumeController@resume', $resume)`. You may have to rearrange the order of your two url same routes. I highly recommend that you make them separate urls or remove the parameter from the one.

Solution to Current Problem: You can run `php artisan route:list` and it'll give you an output of every single valid route. From there, you'll be able to see the issue.

Side note: You can use `any` instead of `match`.

Comment: I simply altered both the name of the function within the controller and the Route. I also updated the limks accordingly and it worked.